# Subnetting and switch configuration (CISCO Packet tracer)

Tags: switch, ipv4, interface

I'd like to ask couple questions that I have about subnetting and switch configuration (more about latter).

Currently, I have subnetted my network to be on IP 192.168.10.0/29 with subnet mask 255.255.255.240 following this logic, my effective IP range for host machines is 192.168.10.1 - 192.168.10.14 because 0 and 15 are reserved.

Knowing this, if I have an office with say 5 machines which are connected to a switch, does this mean that when it comes to configuring the interfaces on the switch I should use each of the IP's within the above range for each interface? This seems highly inefficient if say I have multiple offices or rooms. Now I know that interfaces can be selected as a range i.e. interface range f0/2-14, but I can't set an IP range like 192.168.10.2-192.168.10.14. My current thought process is that I should configure each interface manually to assign the IP addresses incrementally.

I would appreciate if somebody could point out any potential misunderstandings I might have about this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the subnet mask 255.255.255.240 equates to /28, not /29.

Second, switch interfaces are layer 2, so they do not have IP addresses. Switches forward Ethernet frames and are unaware of IP addresses.

Your computers and router interface will have IP addresses in that range.  You trade efficiency for flexibility (growth potential).